# react-google-login not compatible with React 18 What is an alternative?

Tags: reactjs, google-api, google-oauth, google-authenticator

I'm working on a React 18 application, and I want to add Google Authentication to it. However, when I try to use the react-google-login library, I encounter an error indicating that it's not compatible with my React version.

Is there an alternative solution or library that I can use to implement Google Authentication in my React 18 application?

[image: Here's the error ss]

Comment: Is there an alternative solution or library - yes, and you could easilly find that out by opening the repository of the library you tried to use and checking Issues page, specifically https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login/issues/545.